What is the locus of the velocity vectors of a spaceship moving in some distance from a black hole?
Someone with a background in mathematics and limited knowledge of physics asks the following question:
Starting from rest, a spaceship is momentarily pushed with a specific amount of kinetic energy in a chosen direction. What is the resulting locus of velocities, considering all possible directions, after one unit of time (one second)? That is the spaceship itself has some velocity and I want to know how the perturbation due to the black hole affects the velocities, considering all possible directions. I also assume that the conditions in all points around the spaceship are identical and the curvature is zero.
Following this initial impulse, the spaceship navigates with a certain velocity. However, once affected by the gravitational pull of a black hole, the resulting velocity may differ in both direction and magnitude.
Consideration is given to the following cases:

The spaceship is located far from the black hole.

The spaceship is situated close to the event horizon.

The spaceship crosses the event horizon.


By the way, I choose the local coordinate system. The Euclidean!

I tried to use Newton's energy conservation and force laws. Those approximations are good only far from the event horizon. To understand what happens close to a black hole, you have to learn General Relativity.

I am from mathematics and a bit too old to learn general relativity :)
I just hope some one can give me some clue how to deal with the problem

Then you will have to rely on getting an answer rather than doing the calculation yourself.

a circle, case 1 Why are you talking about circles rather than spheres? Space is three-dimensional, not two-dimensional.

In Newtonian physics, maximum power doesn’t cause a particular velocity. It causes a particular acceleration. If the engines keep providing thrust, the rocket keeps going faster and faster.

About the circle, yes you are right. I corrected it and yes I need and answer!

Point number 3 doesn't even make sense as written, what does it mean to be between the event horizon?

I had forgotten to complete it. Now it is corrected!

The black hole is the entire object, event horizon and all so this still doesn't make sense, I'm guessing you mean the singularity.

@safesphere I revise my question then!

I first consider the singularities as the origin of the coordinate system. Then I calculate the gravity vector at the point at which the spaceship is at rest, let point p. Then I consider the new coordinate system whose origin is at the point p.
